# How do I retrieve the numeric address of an object with overloaded stringification

Tags: perl

Here's an easy one I think, but I don't see anywhere else that this has been asked:

When you are in the debugger, you can see both the type as well as the hex "numeric address" of an arrayref or hashref by just printing the variable:

```
    DB<1> $x = [ qw(1 2 3) ]
    DB<2> p $x
    ARRAY(0x1c11ef0)
```

The class part I can get using ref($x), but how can I reliably get just the numeric address, even when I have a hashref whose class uses stringification?

CONTEXT: I'm asking because I have classes where I have a custom "stringify", and this hex address is something that can help me debug duplicate copies and such issues, which it so happens I care about, so I'd like to include this numeric address in the stringified output.

RESEARCH: I looked at perldoc perlref and it only talked about how you can get the ref() part, not the numeric address part.

Comment: If you treat a reference as a scalar, you'll get the address e.g. `perl -e 'print [],{},\""'`

Comment: Actually, I thought Ben's suggestion would work, but noting the "CONTEXT" above, it actually does not work with a stringified object.  So it appears my question is actually harder than I thought, because this simple answer will not do what I want. Again, I have a class defined with stringification, meaning when I print the object, I get something nicer looking, as I want; however, I really want and need that numeric address bit.  I thought $x + 0 would work, but it does not work anymore once the thing is "blessed."

Comment: I'm not picky if it's hex or not hex.  I can convert it after all.  I just want anything that works at this point to get me this numeric address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to use [`Scalar::Util`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html), where `refaddr()` returns memory address as integer,

```
use Scalar::Util 'refaddr';

use CGI;
print "$_\n" for map refaddr($_), ([], {}, \1, CGI->new);
```

output

```
158548440
158551464
158619528
158551512
```

Comment: I have my own object instance, of my own class/package, and it has stringification so it no longer emits output like "MyClass=HASH(0x1c11ef0)."  It emits something like "MyClass with 14 states."  And CGI->new generates a blessed hashref but the CGI class does not possess stringification.

Comment: @user62177541 if you're using overloading in your class, check update.

Comment: Eureka, yes, I believe Scalar::Util refaddr is exactly what I was looking for.  I have been testing these with the actual code and this is the first one that works.  That hexaddr bit above though I'm not using.

Answer (score 0):

Overloaded operators can be disabled within a lexical scope using the [`no overloading`](https://metacpan.org/pod/overloading) pragma:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime;

my $now = DateTime->now;
{
   no overloading;
   printf "refaddr: %d  scalar: %s\n", ~~$_, $_ for [],{},\0,$now;
}
print $now,"\n";
```

output:

```
refaddr: 22987080  scalar: ARRAY(0x15ec148)
refaddr: 30100856  scalar: HASH(0x1cb4d78)
refaddr: 23314768  scalar: SCALAR(0x163c150)
refaddr: 30100688  scalar: DateTime=HASH(0x1cb4cd0)
2015-02-23T17:33:44
```